# Incorrect range value in Pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have some of the data as below. I wrote a query that takes the latest data of certain regions from this data, grouped them according to date_name from this data, and put the value1_gpu value between 2 and 8 (including 2 and 8). But in my query, apart from 2-8 values, out-of-range values such as 24 are also coming. How can I write the correct query?

Data:

```
   { {
   ID:0,
      metadata: {"region": "eu-1"},
      Date: 2011-05-02
   data:[
      {
         Name:'Chris',
         value1_gpu:2,
         created_date:2011-04-03,
         Value3:10
      },
         {
         Name:'Chris',
         value1_gpu:2,
         created_date:2011-04-01,
         Value3:10
      },
      {
         Name:'David',
         value1_gpu:8,
         created_date:2011-04-02,
         Value3:30
      },
     {
         Name:'Mary',
         value1_gpu:12,
         created_date:2011-04-03
         Value3:30
      }
   ]
},
   {
   ID:1,
   metadata: {"region": "eu-2"},
   Date: 2011-05-01
   data:[
      {
         Name:'Chris',
         value1_gpu:80,
         created_date:2011-04-05,
         Value3:100
      },
      {
         Name:'David',
         value1_gpu:60,
         created_date:2011-04-05,
         Value3:30
      }
   ]
},  
    {
   ID:2,
      metadata: {"region": "eu-1"},
      Date: 2011-04-29
   data:[
      {
         Name:'Chris1',
         value1_gpu:2,
         created_date:2011-04-03,
         Value3:10
      },
      {
         Name:'David',
         value1_gpu:8,
         created_date:2011-04-02,
         Value3:30
      },
     {
         Name:'Mary',
         value1_gpu:12,
         created_date:2011-04-03
         Value3:30
      }
   ]
}}
```

My Query:

```
mongo.instances.aggregate([{"$match": {"$and": [{"metadata.region": 'eu-1'},
                             {"data.value1_gpu": { "$gte": 2, "$lte": 8}}]}},
                           {"$sort": {"Date": -1}},
                           {"$limit": 1},
                           {"$unwind": "$data"},
                           {"$group": {
                           "_id": "$data.name",
                           "created_date": {"$first": "$data.created"},
                           "value1_gpu": {"$first": "$data.value1_gpu"}
                            }}])
```

Example Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From your explanation, you just need to shift your unwind stage to before the match stage containing the match of value1_gpu.

I removed the limit as I have no clue as to what you are trying to do with it.

You could also speed up your aggregation by separating the match for region to before unwind stage (as shown below) as well as adding a project stage before the unwind stage.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$data"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "metadata.region": "eu-1"
        },
        {
          "data.value1_gpu": {
            "$gte": 2,
            "$lte": 8
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "Date": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$data.Name",
      "created_date": {
        "$first": "$data.created_date"
      },
      "value1_gpu": {
        "$first": "$data.value1_gpu"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Result from your dataset:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "David",
    "created_date": "2011-04-02",
    "value1_gpu": 8
  },
  {
    "_id": "Chris1",
    "created_date": "2011-04-03",
    "value1_gpu": 2
  },
  {
    "_id": "Chris",
    "created_date": "2011-04-03",
    "value1_gpu": 2
  }
]
```

[MongoDB Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cq1cNC1C38i)